# Making a link in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm really really newbie in Ruby on Rails...
I'm trying to make a link to another page in my project, where it's listed the posts that belong to an escuela.

This is what I did:

In posts_controller.rb I wrote:

```
def postesc
    @posts = Post.where(:escuela_id => params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # postesc.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

In config/routes.rb I wrote:

```
match 'postesc' => 'posts#postesc'
```

In view/escuelas/listaesc.html.erb I wrote the link:

```
<%= link_to "Escuelas", :controller => "posts", :action => "postesc" %>
```

And in view/escuelas/postesc.html.erb I want to make a list of the matching posts.
But this page appears just blank, with only the layout.

Please, some help?

Answer (score 2):

First make the association between post and escuela, then you can find it just by

```
Escuela.find(params[:id]).posts
```

Change your routes to -

```
resources :posts do
  get 'postesc', :on => :collection
end
```

View :

```
<%= link_to "List posts", postesc_posts_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

make a change in routes.rb as

get 'postesc' => 'posts#postesc'

try...<%= link_to "Escuelas", postesc_path %>

OR

```
 <%= link_to "Escuelas", { :controller => "posts", :action => "postesc" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing to add an ID for the Escuela to be selected - as you're doing in your Controller#postesc Action (as in words: where: escuela_id => params[:id]).

```
<%= link_to "Escuela", :controller => "posts", :action => "postesc", :id => 1 %>
```

but you could use the object-link method using the following syntax (by changing your routes a litte):

```
# in routes.rb
match 'postesc' => 'posts#postesc', on: :collection, as: 'esc_index'

# in your view
<%- for escuela in @escuelas do %>
  <%= link_to "Escuela", esc_index(escueal) %>
<% end %>
```